# generic creation of a comma separated string list from a collection

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection

I have the following code. The first line should be the comma separated headers string and the remaining should be the content of my collection layed out to be written to a comma separated file. How do i get the values out?

```
public static List<string> ToListOfStrings<T>(this List<T> items, string sep)
{
    var NewList = new List<string>();
    //string tempHeaderString = "";

    PropertyInfo[] props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

    string s = string.Empty;
    foreach (var prop in props)
    {
        s += prop.Name + sep;

    }
    NewList.Add(s + System.Environment.NewLine);
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        string s1 = string.Empty;
        var values = new object[props.Length];
        for (var i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
        {
            s1 += (props[i].GetValue(item, null)).ToString() + sep;
        }

        NewList.Add(s1 + System.Environment.NewLine);
    }

    return NewList;
}
```

My target Object T only has strings as member properties.

Best

B

Comment: I do correctly get my headers out

Comment: And: what is wrong with the rest of the code?

Comment: I don't get the expected data out. I get the types of the properties.

Comment: The default `ToString()` method returns the type of object. Value types override this and return the value as a string. Can you share the type of one of these problematic properties and the _expected_ output for that property value?

Comment: @BertrandPaul I'm not sure what you are try to achieve. You want a comma seperated list from your items-collection? Why you need the properties then?

Comment: @BertrandPaul you need to override `ToString()` method in classes that you want to use or create special method for converting object value to string base on `Type`.

Comment: @C.Ev... I get soemthing along this out: LINQPad.User.TaskLog,LINQPad.User.Header after the correct header

Comment: @C.Evenhuis is right, It depends on your type. If you have an `enum` for example it will output the enum name not the int value. If the type is object then the `.ToString()` will output the namespace of the class that is stored there

Comment: @Andrey, so there is no generic way to achieve this without having to "Tostring()" each property of my actual object?

Comment: Can someone suggest any code for this?

Comment: Because your value is object. And object.ToString(); doesn't give you the string representation of your value. Try Convert.ToString(props[i].GetValue(item,null)) + sep;

Comment: @Sebi, I still get the namespaces out with your sugestion

Comment: @BertrandPaul Yes you have custom Types in it. Then you need special method or overloaded ToString(); Watch the answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Say you have the following object:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then say you had the following piece of code:

```
User user = new User { Name = "Pete", Password = "Secret" };
Console.WriteLine(user.ToString());
```

It would output `MyNamespace.User, MyAssembly`. What would you *expect* it to output? `Pete`? `Secret`?

The framework cannot decide this *for* you, so you'll have to come up with your own solution. If you own the class, you can add your own `ToString()` implementation:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return Name;
}
```

However if you do not own the code, you'll have to write a converter for each type separately, if you want any control over which property will provide the value for your CSV.

Comment: My idea was that since i'm using just primitive types, it would be possible via reflection to get the type of those properties and just "ToString()" them.

Comment: @BertrandPaul That would make sense, yeah, but it appears that not all these properties are primitive types - you could verify this by inspecting or logging the `prop.PropertyType` when you're collecting the headers.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand from comment only problem in your code is string representation of property value. I've simplified code a bit and created special method where you can place logic to convert value to string, or you can just overload `ToString()` method for type if it's your types in properties.

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> ToListOfStrings<T>(this List<T> items, string sep)
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        yield return properties.Select(p => p.Name).CreateRow(sep);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            yield return properties.Select(p => GetString(p.GetValue(item, null))).CreateRow(sep);
        }
    }

    private static string CreateRow(this IEnumerable<string> values, string separator)
    {
        return string.Join(separator, values) + System.Environment.NewLine;
    }

    public static string GetString(object obj)
    {
        //custom logic to create string from values
        return obj.ToString();
    }
```

**Update:**

According to you comment your also want to display properties of nested objects. this could be done like this:

```
    public static IEnumerable<string> ToListOfStrings<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, string sep)
    {
        var properties = typeof(T).GetInstanceProperties();
        yield return properties.Select(p => p.Name).CreateRow(sep);

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            yield return properties.GetValues(item, sep).CreateRow(sep);
        }
    }

    private static string CreateRow(this IEnumerable<string> values, string separator)
    {
        return values.JoinStrings(separator) + System.Environment.NewLine;
    }

    private static string JoinStrings(this IEnumerable<string> values, string separator)
    {
        return string.Join(separator, values);
    }

    public static PropertyInfo[] GetInstanceProperties(this Type type)
    {
        return type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> GetValues(this IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> properties, object obj, string separator)
    {
        return properties.Select(p => GetString(p.GetValue(obj, null), separator));
    }

    public static string GetString(object obj, string separator)
    {
        var type = obj.GetType();
        if (type.IsPrimitive || type.IsEnum || type == typeof(string))
            return obj.ToString();

        var result = obj.GetType().GetInstanceProperties()
                        .GetValues(obj, separator)
                        .JoinStrings(separator);

        return string.Format("({0})", result);
    }
```

I've wrapped nested object in brackets to show hierarchy of values and preserve consistence of header row.

Comment: @BertrandPaul it will still give same result, You need to add your logic in `GetString` method. You need to know for each type what you need to show as value, there are no generic way for this.

Comment: What i want is that my "ToString()) should return a string which is make up of the comman separated vlues of all the properties of my cutom object.

Comment: I Imagined that this could be automated( The object has 15 properties) But i now understand i have to do this manually, on property at a time.

Comment: @BertrandPaul I've update answer according to your addition info. You may also consider use different separator for first level of object and for nested properties to preserve hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code and it works fine for such properties of `T`, which are of basic types such as `string` or `int`.

```
class Test
{
    public string FString { get; set; }
    public int FInt { get; set; }
}

/* ... */

List<Test> x = new List<Test>
{
    new Test {FString = "A", FInt = 10}, new Test {FString = "B", FInt = 20}
};
```

Output:

```
FString;FInt;
A;10;
B;20;
```

So there is no problem with the code itself.

What I understand from your comments there are some custom classes used as types of the fields in `T` (such as `LINQPad.User.Header`). As others have mentioned each class is solely responsible for *representing itself as a string* by overloading `ToString()`. Only a class can understand how to convert its content into meaningful (though usually stripped) string representation. The very default is to tell the name of the class. This obviously is not what you expect here.

You want to tell the compiler somehow *how* you want to represent `LINQPad.User.Header` as a string. The very basic option - if you are creator of this class is to replace default `ToString()` with custom implementation. Another solution would be to subclass `LINQPad.User.Header` and override `ToString()` in a subclass. Still not sure whether this is easily applied in your scenario. Yet another option is to recognize during CSV creation, that the object you are dealing with *is* a `LINQPad.User.Header` and write it out accordingly (by using its public fields i.e.).

Using `Convert.ToString(props[i].GetValue(item,null))` is not an option since `Convert` also doesn't know *how* to represent a random class as a string.

Comment: The properties of my class are only string. No fancy types in my class. Is there a way with this new information?

Comment: No, since your classes probably contain multiple string fields. Please take a look at @C.Evenhuis answer - how is compiler supposed to know which fields to use as a representation?

Comment: I thought this was the idea with reflection, to determine types at run-time. This is what i do in the first part of my code to get the headers. I learned something here :-)

Comment: A reflection could do, but there two levels of reflection needed here and you use only one. One is to discover what type are the properties of the `T` being passed (this is my `Test`). Since you know these properties are of types such as `LINQPad.User.Header` - another level would be to discover properties of `LINQPad.User.Header`. How to represent this in CSV is the another question.